# Rollback edits allowed while edits pending

Tags: bug, edits, rollbacks

When an edit is pending on a post, further edits are not allowed. Clicking "edit" brings up the edit review instead of the post editor. This flow makes sense.

However, when an edit is pending on a post, you *can* still rollback to previous revisions, which counts as an edit. You can do this by viewing the edit history of the post (if there is any) and clicking "rollback". This all, of course, assumes you have enough rep to edit posts.

I *think* this is a bug: Not allowing edits while another edit is pending review makes sense, and the fact that rollback edits are still allowed seems like an oversight. Rollbacks should not be allowed if other edits are also not allowed. Either that, or *all* edits should be allowed when an edit is pending. Either way, consistency.

Also I noticed that applying a rollback does *not* seem to cancel any existing pending edit.

I do not actually know what happens if you apply a rollback while another edit is pending, and that edit ends up approved, and there is a conflict.

Comment: Edits *are* allowed when a suggestion is pending (and will immediately cancel it without affecting rejection stats), but the UI conceals this in general to minimize the effect of careless overruling. However, opening the edit link in a new tab (or using a userscript that adds the link directly rather than relying on the inline editor), or *submitting* an already-begun edit, will trigger this behavior already. It makes sense for rollbacks, being almost as concealed in the UI as middle-click editing, to likewise be able to overrule suggestions.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Oh that makes sense. Applying a rollback doesn't seem to cancel a pending edit though.